# How would you do smartphone BLE indoor detection and positioning?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How would you implement presence detection for a BLE enabled smartphone in an environment with other BLE devices ?
The solution need to be user transparent and need to be working with a smartphone in sleep mode (no action required from the user, and if background process, need to be always active)

In my point of view, two possibilities:

- from the smartphone itself, scanning for other BLE devices
- from other devices, looking for the smartphone

The first possibility is difficult/impossible to implement due to OS restrictions regarding background process.
The second possibility is difficult/impossible to implement due to BLE visibility timeout, which makes the device invisible if we leave a setup page.

What would be your solution ?

Comment: iBeacon with an app on the phone

Comment: This could be a solution, iBeacon in the environment, and then scan for these Beacons from the phone. But how to ensure the BLE scan is always running and never killed or disabled in background ?

Comment: Well, you can never guarantee "never" since the user is in control, but Core Location beacon monitoring remains active in the background if the user gives permission for your app to use background location services

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak in detail about iOS.

For that platform there are big advantages in using iBeacons. (A special use-case of BLE with OS support.) The location manager has support for registering iBeacons as "locations", and the OS notifies your app when you enter a new beacon region. It will even launch your app if it isn't running.

That neatly solves the problem of getting notified whether your app is running at the time or not.

On the downside you can only monitor 20 unique beacon regions at a time. It is possible to make multiple beacons be part of the same region, and if you're clever you can use that to manage a larger number of points (you'd use a beacon beacon that has wildcard for the major or minor version number, and then interrogate that parameter when the beacon is actually detected.)

Positioning is all but impossible. In theory you can do "trilateration" where you use distance readings from multiple beacons to figure out the location, but in practice the range data is too sloppy and variable to do much good.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I have read about Region Monitoring and iBeacon, for iOS 7 or later: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

If I understand well, the OS now "listen" for surrounding beacons and pay attention to the GPS coordinates so that we can both wake up an app when entering range of a beacon and wake up an app when entering a specified location.

Comment: Not really the GPS location. You can interpret it that way if you want, but it's really just in range of a BLE transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

I built a Bluetooth device detector a while back, and the problem I ran into is that most devices simply do not broadcast themselves. If they do not, there is no way to find them.

What you need to implement is an app on the phone which does the scanning in the background and location specific Bluetooth broadcasters.  You would then use the smartphones data connection to figure out where the device is.

This was my undergrad thesis in '2012 so if you'd like I could dredge it up and send it to you out of band.

Comment: Yes, background application would be a solution to scan from the smartphone side. My only concern is not being killed in background :/
I would be interested in your thesis if you can send me a link in private please.

Comment: my email is johnjustinlee@me.com, you'll have to ping me